# When I try verify test purchase product - got error 410 ? Purchase.product get

Tags: android, google-api, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-console

I’m trying to verify test product purchase on server side but something is going wrong. 
I created service account with role (viewer) and added financial permissions, Linked app,
On server side got acces token to be able to consume API.
Make request according to documentation https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get#request-body

with such url

/androidpublisher/v2/applications/{package_name}/purchases/products/{product_id}/tokens/{purchase_token}

and got error 410
I'll be much appreciate if somebody could help.

Comment: Are you sure you can still use the v2 api? The link that you included has v3 in url.

Comment: [MarcinG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2908993/marcing) Thank you for your answer. I will find out, server side writing not me

Comment: @marcing add your comment as an answer i'll accept as correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you can still use the v2 api? The link that you included has v3 in url.

Comment: Thank you !
App was using an old version of the Google Play Developer API. versions 1 and 2 of this API will no longer be available, and any calls to these versions will fail.